# How can I set click event for 3-d object in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to set Click event for multiple spheres in wpf page. The spheres are like a cube. Then I want to change the color of each sphere by clicking on it. Here is the method to create my model.

```
private void DefineModel(Model3DGroup model_group)

{

    int myRow = enteredRow / 2;
    int myCol = enteredColumn / 2;
    int myDep = enteredScale / 2;

    // Make spheres centered at (+/-1, 0, 0).
    MeshGeometry3D mesh1 = new MeshGeometry3D();
    for (int i = 0; i < enteredRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < enteredColumn; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < enteredScale; k++)
            {
                AddSmoothSphere(mesh1, new Point3D(-k, -j, -i), 0.25, 10, 20);
            }
        }
    }


    SolidColorBrush brush1 = Brushes.Green;
    DiffuseMaterial material1 = new DiffuseMaterial(brush1);
    GeometryModel3D model1 = new GeometryModel3D(mesh1, material1);
    model_group.Children.Add(model1);

}
```

Comment: I think it's a bit more fiddly than just a click event. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27e68baa-8e52-40f7-9d1a-f283faec5051/handle-click-event-on-children-of-viewport3d?forum=wpf

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the location of 3-d objects

Comment: You don't need to know where the 3d objects are. You get the position from the mouse event and whatever is at that position ( was clicked ) from a hit test at that position. You get a 3d object out the hittest, or not. From that you will have to use some logic like check name/tag/reference/whatever to work out which one.